# Grabbing a number from string output on command line

Tags: command-line, text-processing

How do I grab only the number from a command line output.

For example, I have a program which on being run outputs a string like

```
submitted batch with job number 12345
```

I would like to grab only the number `12345` and pipe it to another program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest form to get only the number from the string you have provided is as follows.

```
string="submitted batch with job number 12345"
echo $string | grep -o '[0-9]\+'
```

This will fail if the string or output of your program does include a second number group like

```
string="submitted 1 batch with job number 12345"
```

In that case, you would could use `sed` to e.g. search for the string *number* and only match for numbers after that occurrence.

```
echo $string | sed -n 's/^.*number\ \([0-9]\+\)/\1/p'
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm not able to accept the answer due to my rating but this works wonderful!

Comment: We can use `| tail -1` to cut only the last result, if there are more than one.

Comment: Save the pipe subshell with a [here string](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17837.html), e.g. `grep -o '[0-9]\+' <<< "$string"`.

Comment: No need to specify the beginning of the line and to escape the space character in quotes – and no need to negate and print it: `sed 's/.*number \([0-9]\+\)/\1/' <<< "$string"`